# What to wear to walk to showers: clothes or towel?

Tags: camping, tents, clothing, walking

This will be my first tent camping trip in my life. And I don't know what to wear to the showers. I usually sleep naked in the summer so my preference is for just wrapping a towel around my waist and walking to the showers with toiletry bag in hand and flip flops on my feet. I will be camping in a caravan park between 2 towns.

Edit: I will be camping along the coast between two suburbs of Cape Town, South Africa. (I forgot about the location/culture aspect.)

Comment: It might help to know what country this is in as it might (I'm not sure) be something that varies between countries.

Comment: @Phil Right. For example, I could add another answer stating that, from my experience in Germany, both options are fine.

Comment: Based on my experience in organized campgrounds in EU and NA both would be fine. Even just swimming trunks. In many paces you dont have a lot of room to put your stuff while you take a shower.

Comment: I echo what Phil said. This will massively depend on location. OP please state it.

Comment: @RedWolf321 You can merge your two accounts.  Go to http://meta.outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/788/can-a-moderator-please-merge-my-two-accounts-one-of-which-was-created-before-I for how.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your input. I will just wear a shorts to and from the bathroom with flip flops.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I wear my swimming trunks to the shower.  My wife wears a pull over sun dress (light weight, thigh length).  We wear our shower shoes, we carry our towels and shower supplies. We usually just take soap and shampoo. The soap is in a small plastic container.

We wear the same clothing both ways. Dressing and other hygiene activities are done when we get back to camp, from the shower.

Our dress is appropriate for the campground even if we are not on the way to/from the shower.  It is light enough to dry quickly.

Campgrounds very greatly, when it comes to the quality of the bath/shower/toilet facilities. We travel a lot and seldom stop at the same location.  We find this solution works anyplace.

Answer (score 10):

This will be very country and even camp ground specific.

Least likely to offend approach is to do what most of the others do. If just one person is doing what you want, don't presume its acceptable, wait till you have seen several people doing it.

If everyone is getting dressed to go to showers (unlikely), get dressed. In the unlikely even most people walk naked to the showers, you are unlikely to offend with just your towel for modesty. Keep in mind what is acceptable in the early morning and/or dark may no longer be accepted once the sun comes up and kids come out to play. What people accept at 3AM may get you kicked out or arrested at 3PM.

Answer (score 6):

I've been camping in the UK for many years and the generally people either get fully dressed before heading to the shower, or walk over in pajamas/ dressing gown.

Answer (score 2):

I would wear shorts to the shower. That way you don't accidentally lose your towel and end up flashing everyone.